# Glance command output in a text file

Tags: unix

In a UNIX machine I want to convert the output of a glance command in a text file so that i can later 'grep' the required information.

Is it possible to do it?

```
 Glance C.05.00.000             03:28:23 hht013a4     ia64                                                                          Current  Avg  High
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CPU  Util   S                                                                                                                        |  4%    4%    4%
Disk Util   F  F                                                                                                                     |  3%    3%    3%
Mem  Util   S                      SU                                                                                    UF    F     | 96%   96%   96%
Swap Util   U                                                                              UR                     R                  | 86%   86%   86%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                     PROCESS LIST                                                         Users=    2
                         User      CPU %    Thrd Disk        Memory       Block
Process Name     PID     Name   ( 400% max) Cnt  IOrate      RSS/VSS      On
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
glance             11441 jg212p        9.5     1  12.8     1.5mb    7.0mb SLEEP
nfs_async_io          44 root          0.0     2   0.0   187.8mb  211.3mb SYSTM
java                4663 acssim2       0.0    65   0.0    1.72gb   2.95gb SLEEP
java               17992 websphe2      0.0   101   0.0   840.2mb   1.73gb SLEEP
java               16811 websphe1      0.0    98   0.0   791.6mb   1.71gb SLEEP
java               29155 websphe4      0.0    87   0.0   565.6mb   1.71gb SLEEP
java               22322 isadm         0.0    31   0.0   123.8mb  442.9mb SLEEP
java               29003 websphe3      0.0    87   0.0   572.4mb   1.71gb SLEEP
java               28530 websphe1      0.0    88   0.0   583.4mb   1.71gb SLEEP
java                5836 websphe1      0.0   149   0.0    2.40gb   2.84gb SLEEP
java               12411 acssim5       0.0    66   0.0    1.90gb   2.96gb SLEEP
java               23341 acssim3       0.0    71   0.0    2.35gb   3.09gb SLEEP
java               23524 websphe5      0.0    97   0.0   797.0mb   1.72gb SLEEP
java               21153 websphe4      0.0    97   0.0   802.7mb   1.72gb SLEEP
java               19243 acssim6       0.0    59   0.0    1.71gb   2.93gb SLEEP
```

Comment: use `glance ... > filename`

Answer (score 0):

You could use -f option which will send additional copy of the output to a file in addition to displaying it on screen. Something like:

```
glance -f myfile.out
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get results and avoid output in the terminal is to use `adviser_only` mode.

From `glance` man:

> ```
>   -aos filename  Use this option  as  an  alternative  to  -adviser_only
>                  -syntax filename option.
>
>
>   -iterations count
>                  This option allows you to limit the number of intervals
>                  that  Glance will run.  This can be used in conjunction
>                  with the -adviser_only option which enables  glance  to
>                  run in the background with no terminal screen displays.
>                  Glance  will  execute  for  the  number  of  iterations
>                  specified  and  then  terminate.  The minimum iteration
>                  value is 2 which will be used if the count is specified
>                  as 2 or less.
> ```

A real world example:

```
glance -aos gl.syn -iterations 2 > gl.out
```

Having:

```
$ cat gl.syn 
print "CPU total:",gbl_cpu_total_util_cum|3|0
```

Result:

```
$ cat gl.out 
CPU total:7.5%
CPU total:7.6%
```